# c++11 union contains data member with virtual function

Tags: c++, c++11, unions

```
#include <iostream>
class derive1{
  public:
    derive1() = default;
    ~derive1() = default;
    virtual void func() { std::cout << "derive 1" << std::endl; }
};

class derive2 {
  public:
    derive2() = default;
    ~derive2() = default;
    virtual void func() { std::cout << "derice 2" << std::endl; }
};

union classUnion {
  classUnion() {};
  ~classUnion() {};
  derive1 obj1;
  derive2 obj2;
};

int main() {
  classUnion u1;
  u1.obj1.func();  // <-- OK print 'derive 1'
  derive1 &dev1 = u1.obj1;
  dev1.func(); // <-- OK print 'derive 1'
  derive1 *ptr = &(u1.obj1);
  ptr->func(); // <-- core dump/seg fault
  return 0;
}
```

I thought C++11 allow non-trivial constructor (with virtual function).
I can't see what's the problem here.
I use
  "g++ -std=c+11 test.cpp" to compile it (gcc 4.8 and gcc 5.0).

Comment: You never constructed anything.

Comment: C++11 allows non-trivial constructors, but they have to be invoked manually (the compiler itself cannot know what member of the union you want to "activate")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you never initialize the object inside the union. At least, the easiest way to make it work is the following little tweak:

```
union classUnion {
  classUnion() {};
  ~classUnion() {};
  derive1 obj1={}; // unions can have one inline initializer
  derive2 obj2;
};
```

However, if you instead do this:

```
int main() {
  classUnion u1;
  u1.obj1 = derive1{};
  ...
}
```

It still will crash. The reason why is because you are assigning into an uninitialized object, and in particular you have a user defined destructor (i.e. a virtual one).

Consider the following:
(http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union.)

> If members of a union are classes with user-defined constructors and
>   destructors, to switch the active member, explicit destructor and
>   placement new are generally needed:

So to realistically use classes with virtual functions (which typically need virtual destructors), you're going to need to use placement new and manual destruction calls, like so:

```
int main() {
  classUnion u1;
  new (&u1.obj1) derive1{};
  ... // use obj1
  u1.obj1.~derive1();
  new (&u1.obj2) derive2{};
  ... // use obj2
  u1.obj2.~derive2();
}
```

Comment: `=` doesn't work because you are calling a member function on a nonexistent object.

Comment: @T.C. Funny I revised my guess at the exact moment of your comment. Yeah I guess that's it. I suppose I could modify the answer to reduce the speculative nature of it.

Answer (score 2):

None of the calls to `func()` in your example are *OK*, they're all undefined behavior. A `union` does not default initialize any of its members; if it were to do so, which one would it initialize?

To demonstrate this, add a non-static data member to `derive1` and print it within `func()`, you'll either see garbage values or your program will crash earlier.

```
class derive1{
  public:
    derive1() = default;
    ~derive1() = default;
    virtual void func() { std::cout << "derive 1 " << i << std::endl; }
    int i = 20;
};
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c4624ee0458cef4d)

To fix your example, either change the `union` constructor to construct `obj1` in the *mem-initializer-list*

```
classUnion() : obj1() {};
```

or add a *brace-or-equal* initializer for `obj1`

```
 derive1 obj1 = {};
```

---

As for why the first 2 calls to `func()` in your example seemed to work, I'm guessing gcc inlined those function calls, but it didn't do so when dealing with the `derived1 *`, which caused the last call to fail.