# Best practices for run-time polymorphism for Embedded C++? ROMable run-time polymorphism?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, embedded, dynamic-memory-allocation, bare-metal

I require run-time polymorphism in my embedded c++ project. In my research on best practices for embedded c++ I have found that it is recommended that objects be declared in static memory and to avoid dynamic allocation (new/delete/malloc/free) as much as possible if not entirely.

Below is what I have come up with for run-time polymorphism in embedded C++. The idea is that you dynamically allocate the InterfaceA object, use it immediately and then delete it. You do not hold any instances of that interface class. Any persistent data would be picked up ( e.g. get_index() ) from the interface class and stored externally. Anytime you need to operate with interface functions, you re-allocate the interface, use it immediately and delete it. This would avoid using the heap as much as possible.

This seems not fully optimal. Since I am not storing any static data within the interface I hope there is a way for me to use the interface statically.

**What is the best way to do run-time polymorphism while avoiding dynamic allocation?**

**Bonus: Is there any way to do run-time polymorphism while keeping the application (mostly) ROMable?**

```
class A
{
    public:
        int index;
        int init(int type);
}

int A::init(int type)
{
    Interface* interface = SelectInterface(type);
    index = interface->get_index(type);
    delete interface;
}
```

And then I have the following interface:

```
// ----------- INTERFACES -------------- //

class Interface
{
    virtual int get_index() = 0;
}

// This is the interface factory
Interface* SelectInterface(int type)
{
    if (type == 0)
    { 
        return new InterfaceA();
    }
    else if (type == 1)
    {
        return new InterfaceB();
    }

    return null;
}

class InterfaceA :: public Interface
{
    InterfaceA();
    int get_index();
} 

int InterfaceA::get_index()
{
    return 5;
}

class InterfaceB :: public Interface
{
    InterfaceB();
    int get_index();
} 

int InterfaceB::get_index()
{
    return 6;
}
```

Comment: please fix the syntax error in your code, they distract from the actual question and provoke comments like this one

Comment: You could store the interface implementations in global variables and have `SelectInterface` return a pointer or reference to the global.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the other answer and comments I would not advice using dynamic memory allocation in embedded environments. It is very important to have deterministic behavior with regards to your limited memory. When running bare metal it is really hard / not possible to catch out of memory exceptions. Using an RTOS will give you a little more flexibility but not much.

However it is possible. To make your program us polymorphism without dynamic memory allocation you can achieve this by using a [union](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union) as of C++11 or a [variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) as of C++17. You can use those to statically allocate memory and initialize the actual object later. To support multiple objects you could use a limited size array.

The following example constructs a static array of unions for your interface. The factory function initializes the memory in the union. The clear function calls the destructor to clear the union.

```
#include <array>

template<int SIZE>
class Buffer
{
  private:
    union DataUnion 
    {
      // These are required. Please check the documenation of unions.
      DataUnion() {};
      ~DataUnion() {};

      // Actual data in the union.
      InterfaceA a;
      InterfaceB b;
    };

    std::array<DataUnion, SIZE> dataArray;

  public:
    Buffer() = default;
    ~Buffer() = default;

    // This is the interface factory
    Interface* SelectInterface(int type)
    {
      // This function will return null when there is no space. You can easily deal with this 
      // compared to an exception.
      Interface* pointer = nullptr;

      // First check there is space in the array
      // Pseudo code
      if(dataArray.has_space())
      {
        // Pseudo code to get a free union
        DataUnion& union = GetFreeUnion();

        if (type == 0)
        { 
          // Initialize the memory in the union to be of type A.
          // Use the placement new.
          new &(union.a) InterfaceA{};
          pointer = &(union.a);
        }
        else if (type == 1)
        {
          // Initialize the memory in the union to be of type B.
          // Use the placement new.
          new &(union.b) InterfaceB{};
          pointer = &(union.b);
        }
      }
      return pointer;
    }

    // After your done with the object you need to clear the memory.
    void Clear(Interface* pointer_to_data)
    {
      // Pseudo code to find the index in the array.
      int index = FindIndex(pointer_to_data)
      DataUnion& union = dataArray[index];

      // Pseudo code to retrieve the type stored at that index.
      // You need to keep track of that, which is not in this example.
      int type = GetType(index);

      // Now call the destructor of the object to clear the union.
      if(type = 0)
      {
        union.a.~InterfaceA();
      }
      else if(type = 1)
      {
        union.b.~InterfaceB();
      }

      // Update the administration that index is free.
    }
};

// Define the buffer.
Buffer<10> buffer;

main()
{
  // Initiate an instance of a.
  Interface* pA = buffer.SelectInterface(0);
  if(nullptr != pA)
  {
    // Do something.
  }

  // Initiate an instance of b.
  Interface* pB = buffer.SelectInterface(1);
  if(nullptr != pB)
  {
    // Do something.
  }

  // Stop using a.
  buffer.Clear(pA);

  // And on
}
```

There are limitations you have to consider:

1. InterfaceA, InterfaceB and others have a comparable size. If you have one derived class is much bigger it will blow up the memory allocation.
2. You should have a general idea of how many objects you need at the same time. The buffer is always allocated even if you do not use it.
3. Unions do have limitations and need special care. Use them wisely! Read the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union) and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34602648/c11-union-contains-data-member-with-virtual-function).
4. You need to implement code to keep track of which indices are occupied.

At this point I have not yet used the std::variant option. I *suspect* it will be simpler as you do not need the initialize and clear the memory manually.

I hope this answers your question. Yes it is possible to use polymorphism and have static allocation.

If you are looking for more examples on how to use C++ in embedded device you can take a look at the code of [MBED OS](https://os.mbed.com/docs/). I find it very clear C++ code (my opinion) and I find it interesting that ARM, one of the largest mcu designers in the world, has chosen C++ for their code.

Answer (score -2):

Run-time polymorphism, RTTI and dynamic allocation should not be used in bare metal embedded system applications, period. The main reason being that [it doesn't make any sense](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/171257/realloc-wasting-lots-of-space-in-my-mcu/171581#171581). But also because embedded systems should always behave deterministically.

Instead of focusing on what language features you want to use, focus on the purpose of the application - the actual problem you are trying to solve - and then design the program accordingly. Using language features just for the sake of it is how you end up with performance bottlenecks, meta programming, strange bugs and general code bloat.

This is actually the main reason why C is more suitable for embedded systems: most of the features that you shouldn't use are simply not available. You *can* write bare metal programs in C++, but it requires extensive skill and discipline, to know which restricted subset of C++ that can be safely used. Unfortunately, some 90% of all C++ programmers don't have what it takes to do that (even if they think so themselves), so therefore it is better to avoid C++ entirely.

Comment: (PC programmers who have never worked with embedded _hate_ hearing the uncomfortable truth that C++ isn't very suitable for that branch which they themselves have never worked in. Whereas I have programmed C++ and embedded systems for nearly 20 years.)

Comment: -1 I did professionally program embedded for a small company. I switched (against the opinion of my coworker, and senior) the 8-bit controller projects to C++. Retrospectively it was the right decision. It allowed me to write more stable code. I did rewrite most of the companies code, it was a mess and afterwards it worked. Yes, I did  not use heap allocation, or the pitiful polymorphism provided by the C++ OOP mess. You have to know what you are doing, here I agree with your answer. But stating that embedded projects are best programmed in C is plain wrong.

Comment: @ziggystar So you are one of the mention 10%, congratulations. Your co-workers were probably not. And then maybe they have to maintain this project after you. With a full blown standard compliant compiler, that means they are free to add RTTI, exception handling, heap allocation or whatever other bad ideas people who have studied C++ from mainstream programming sources might get.

Comment: Because in C heap allocation is not possible?

Comment: @ziggystar They are perfectly possible but in C it is not sneakly hidden inside standard libs such as inside std::vector or std::string.

Comment: I have to admit that it's now over 10 years, and I can't really remember the details. There were some features in C++ (not in C), which let me write more robust code. I was using some embedded IDEs and compilers (not gcc). Maybe there, it was even an option to not use heap. After all, the compiler (or linker) must allocate some space for the heap.

Comment: @ziggystar So C++ was fantastic but you don't know why.

Comment: I'm also a long-in-the-tooth embedded programmer, and I had a 5-year stint with a company doing desktop/server programming in C++. I loved it. Making user-defined data types that "feel" like built-in types is probably my favorite use of C++, but I also found that I like organizing functionality by classes. Not OOP in the four-pillars sense, but definitely two or three of them (if you dream up your system architecture with pure virtual interface classes and the intention of exclusively using polymorphism in a small embedded project, you're just setting yourself up for performance problems).

Comment: As far as dynamic memory goes, that's generally not a great idea in long-running embedded applications unless your system design includes a periodic intentional reboot to clean up fragmentation. More workable is to have a limited number of "workspaces" of a small number of predetermined sizes that you can temporarily claim (sort of an application-specific `malloc()`). That way there's never any chance of fragmentation permanently precluding you from getting a needed allocation. Yes, there are best practices for embedded programming, and they differ greatly from best practices in general.